# Is there tool avaialble to check code quality for gherkin language?

Tags: behat, gherkin

I am using behat testing framework to test my website.
In that I need to write .features file in gherkin language.

So I would like to know If there is any tool available that will -

1.Validate correctness of .features files

Or/And

2.Perform static code analysis on .features files

Or/And

3.Perform code quaility check on .features files

For example sonarqube can perform static code analysis on C,Java,PHP language.

Comment: I have heard rumors regarding a linter for Gherkin. What do you foresee that the analyzer would catch? Gherkin is a small language. The sentences would seem hard to check for validity.

Comment: @ThomasSundberg, It should do static analysis of feature file e.g Show error on use of incorrect Gherkin keyword.

Comment: With five keywords, do you really think that you need a static analyser? The syntax is checked when the Gherkin parser reads the file. To me at least, that is enough.

Comment: However, if you think it is needed then feel free to write a analyser and share it with the community. These tools are all open source and only made possible due to a lot of pro bono work.

Comment: Seconding this question, a validator tool that one can run on ``.feature`` files would be much appreciated. Especially considering how underspecified the language is.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Online Gherkin Formatter and Validator](https://www.assertthat.com/gherkin_editor#erlang-dark)

This tool allows you to check syntax and reindent/format feature files.

Comment: this is cool, but i noticed when i remove lines that should invalidate it, it doesnt. for example, using their pre-filled example, if i remove `Scenario Outline` and the first `Given` line, there are no errors reported. There is some color formatting that goes away, so is that part of the validation? seems like i should be alerted of more errors when i purposefully make incorrect syntax

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [CukeTest](http://cuketest.com) on Windows used mainly to author gherkin files and cucumber.js projects, which you can also to author or validate gherkin (*.feature) files.

Take a look at the following image:

[image]

Steps:

1. Open a folder (a.k.a. project) that contains the *.feature
2. Click "Validate Project" button.

CukeTest can either be downloaded directly or installed from Windows Store.

Comment: This is only available for windows?

Comment: it is available for both windows and Mac